# How to record or export the CACA output in FFMPEG?

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, script, pipe

I'm trying to export (pipe) the output device CACA in FFMPEG whithout sucsess.

The script work's fine, but no OUTPUT is recorded.

```
ffmpeg -i final3.mp4 -pix_fmt rgb24 -color fullgray -window_size 244x66 -f caca - | ffmpeg -i - output.mp4
```

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `-f caca -` arguments, you are telling ffmpeg to convert frames of a video to a text approximation of the image, then write the text to your screen via stdout. The output text isn't in a video format, it is text that your terminal or console can understand.

It would be like if you used text to speech to convert a sentence into an audio file, and then tried to take that audio file and pipe it into a text file. To do what you're trying to do, you'll need to account for the fact that the text output needs to be rendered in a terminal (or something like a terminal) and then recaptured.

Luckily there are several routes to do what you're trying to do. I'd start here: http://stariocek.asuscomm.com/watch-ascii-libcaca.html
That page contains a script where ffmpeg is used to output frames of a movie to image files, then the image files are converted to an HTML file (the HTML file would look a lot like the output of libcaca), then those HTML files are output using [img2txt](https://github.com/hit9/img2txt), then those HTML files are rendered to image files with webkit2png, and finally the image files are recombined into a movie using `mencoder`.

An alternative route would be to use VLC to render the video using libcaca (`vlc --vout caca final3.mp4`, then capture the resultant output using a standard desktop capture tool (like QuickTime Screen Recording if you are on a Mac).

Answer (score 0):

Я решил этот вопрос одновременной записью и проигрыванием окна ascii графики при помощи самого ffmpeg. Другого пути нет. Логика одна - захват экрана/окна в реальном времени в файл. Какой инструмент для этого использовать - личный выбор каждого.
В windows для этого удобнее всего использовать cmd скрипт для одновременного запуска двух копий ffmpeg для проигрывания "caca" и захвата экрана окна.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).